# How I can use Face Authentication in Xamarin.android app.when user open app it use face Authentication as login

Tags: android, xamarin.android

> What is the process to Implement face Recognizance Authentication in
> Xamarin.Android to authenticate user to login .how to implement this
> type of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Microsoft Cognitive Services API`. This API allowS you to detect human faces, organize people into groups, find similar faces, and identify previously-tagged faces in images.

To get started for free, visit the `Microsoft Cognitive Services` subscription page, and subscribe to the Face APIs. Once registered, you should have a free subscription to the Face APIs, including API keys.

Please check the MS tutorial.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/adding-facial-recognition-to-your-mobile-apps/

The code sample I focked you could download for reference.
https://github.com/WendyZang/FacialRecognitionLogin

Comment: Zang MSFT Can we use system own attenticatoion.like in mobile when I want to unlock mobile lock i use face Recoganization.Can we use like this type of Attentication

Comment: You need to know what face Authentication is of the device. And find the API to do the facial detection and identification.

Comment: is there types of Face Attentication? @Wendy Zang - MSFT

Comment: As i know,  there is `BiometricPrompt API` for Face Attentication. Please check the link. https://source.android.com/security/biometric/face-authentication